# Remove dictionary entries based on length of key

Tags: python

Do dictionaries allow for filtering based on **key** length? Altering dictionaries conditionally based on value seems straightforward, but what about doing the same with keys? i.e. what would it take to delete all dictionary keys that are not explicitly 4 characters long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
d = {'fooo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'foo': 3}
result = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(k) == 4}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'fooo': 1}
```

Comment: @jetprop this retains keys of length 4, which is the same as discarding keys of length not 4. In fact I think your answer is backwards : )

Comment: @jetprop IMHO, the question ask to remove keys that are not 4 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished as seen in the following:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in old_dict.items() if len(k) == 4}
```

Comment: I believe `!=4` should be `==4` :P

Comment: my mistake. I've fixed it, above.

Comment: If possible please provide more context to your answer to help others in the future @jetprop

Answer (score 0):

As krflol mentioned, if you don't want to build a whole new dictionary but
rather just modify your old dictionary, a straightforward for loop will do:

```
my_dict = {"a": 1, "abcd": 4, "": 9, "xyzt": 16}

for k in list(my_dict):
    if len(k) != 4:
        del my_dict[k]

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using filter, like so :

```
my_dict = dict(filter(lambda k: len(k) != 4, my_dict.items()))
```